# Record and upload audio and video files to the server in android

Tags: android, performance

In my app I need to record the audio or video in less size and need to save it to the media and send into the server. What is the best approach to do this?Without using any thirdparty libraries.Please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to make API on server and just pass your parameters to that API. main functionality will be performed by API.

Comment: Which is best retrofit or volley to upload the media files to server ?

Comment: https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/09/android-upload-image-server-using-volley.html

Comment: I just give you idea because i worked on APIs not in android

Answer (score 0):

Sending the file to the server you will need an upload URL and the file name of the recording, here is the code

Explanation of the code,

1. Open the URL connection and get the stream to which the data will be written.
2. Specify a max buffer which will hold the stream information.

3.Read bytes from the file and write it to the output stream.

4.Get the response and do the necessary actions accordingly.

```
public boolean uploadFileNew(String sourceFileUri) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File upFile=null;       

        try {
            final File root = new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DIR_NAME"));


            root.mkdirs();
            final String tmp[] = sourceFileUri.split(File.separator);
            final String fname = tmp[tmp.length-1];
            upFile = new File(root, fname);



                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(upFile);


                URL url = new URL("YOUR_URL");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Allow Inputs & Outputs.
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                // Set HTTP method to POST.
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; typ=\""+1+"\"; name=\""+fname+"\";filename=\"" + fname + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                int counter = -1;

                in.close();


                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    Log.d("uploadFile", "File Upload Complete.");
                }

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("uploadFile", "File Upload Error:" + ex.toString());

            return false;

        }


        return true;
    }
```